# Respond_to no content rails 4.1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following in my controller, worked on Rails 3.2

```
 def signup
    ::MailchimpSignup.build(params)
    respond_to do |format| <---- Error coming from here.
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

After upgrade to Rails 4.1.9, I get `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

I need it to not redirect, and render no content. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are requesting `json`? e.g `.../signup.json`

Answer (score 0):

Probably when signup are being called, it won't requiring a JSON output. Changing to this should be work.

```
def signup
  ::MailchimpSignup.build(params)
  head :no_content
end
```